# Exception with google bigquery select query to get count of rows in tekton task

Tags: google-bigquery, tekton, tekton-pipelines

I am working on a tekton task to get the count of rows from bigquery table and assign it to a variable for further validation, I have written below query to get the results in tekton task but it is failing with some json error

```
vulnerableImageCount=$(echo $(echo -e 'SELECT CI_PIPELINE.CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME AS IMAGE FROM asdf-f127437220d027.MONITORING.CI_PIPELINE AS CI_PIPELINE, asdf-f127437220d027.MONITORING.CHECKMARX , asdf-f127437220d027.MONITORING.SONARQUBE AS SONARQUBE , asdf-f127437220d027.MONITORING.FOSSA AS FOSSA WHERE CI_PIPELINE.CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME="'"$(params.container_image)"'" AND CI_PIPELINE.CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME=CHECKMARX.CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME AND CHECKMARX.CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME=SONARQUBE.CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME AND SONARQUBE.CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME=FOSSA.CONTAINER_IMAGE_NAME AND ( safe_cast(CHECKMARX.HIGH_SEVERITY as INT64) == 0 AND safe_cast(SONARQUBE.CRITICAL_VIOLATIONS as INT64) == 0 AND safe_cast(SONARQUBE.MAJOR_VIOLATIONS as INT64) == 0 AND safe_cast(FOSSA.CRITICAL_SEVERITY as INT64) == 0 AND safe_cast(FOSSA.HIGH_SEVERITY as INT64) == 0)' | bq query --nouse_legacy_sql --format=json) | jq '.[0]' | jq '.IMAGE')
```

but I am getting below error

```
I0522 13:35:57.637674 140137654602624 bigquery_client.py:730] There is no apilog flag so non-critical logging is disabled.
Error in query string: Error processing job
```

when I run the same query formed through this task in google bigquery, query is executing and I am getting results.

can someone please help me to fix it.